# Masonry JS ignoring CSS transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-animations, jquery-masonry

I am currently having an issue when changing height to my div on click. I am using masonry and bootstrap in order to display a card layout and expand cards to reveal more information on click, but only moving the cards within a column down rather than a row. When I've tried to add transition with CSS, its being ignored and the div only toggles the new height from my class of '.open'. Thanks for the assistance!

Here is a Codepen of the project for reference: https://codepen.io/silasisland/pen/YrXPov

**HTML**

```
<main>
    <section id="wrapper">

        <div class="row grid">
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-override">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="customer-name">
                            <h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-tools">

                            <button class="btn btn-link delete-card"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link card-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-summary">
                            <span class="card-label">ID:</span> 14568536 <br> 123 Main St. <br> CITY, STATE <br> United States of America <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-override">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="customer-name">
                            <h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-tools">

                            <button class="btn btn-link delete-card"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link card-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-summary">
                            <span class="card-label">ID:</span> 14568536 <br> 123 Main St. <br> CITY, STATE <br> United States of America <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-override">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="customer-name">
                            <h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-tools">

                            <button class="btn btn-link delete-card"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link card-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-summary">
                            <span class="card-label">ID:</span> 14568536 <br> 123 Main St. <br> CITY, STATE <br> United States of America <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-override">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="customer-name">
                            <h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-tools">

                            <button class="btn btn-link delete-card"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link card-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-summary">
                            <span class="card-label">ID:</span> 14568536 <br> 123 Main St. <br> CITY, STATE <br> United States of America <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-override">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="customer-name">
                            <h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-tools">

                            <button class="btn btn-link delete-card"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link card-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-summary">
                            <span class="card-label">ID:</span> 14568536 <br> 123 Main St. <br> CITY, STATE <br> United States of America <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-override">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="customer-name">
                            <h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-tools">

                            <button class="btn btn-link delete-card"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link card-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-summary">
                            <span class="card-label">ID:</span> 14568536 <br> 123 Main St. <br> CITY, STATE <br> United States of America <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-override">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="customer-name">
                            <h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-tools">

                            <button class="btn btn-link delete-card"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link card-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-summary">
                            <span class="card-label">ID:</span> 14568536 <br> 123 Main St. <br> CITY, STATE <br> United States of America <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-override">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="customer-name">
                            <h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-tools">

                            <button class="btn btn-link delete-card"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link card-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-summary">
                            <span class="card-label">ID:</span> 14568536 <br> 123 Main St. <br> CITY, STATE <br> United States of America <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-override">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="customer-name">
                            <h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-tools">

                            <button class="btn btn-link delete-card"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link card-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-summary">
                            <span class="card-label">ID:</span> 14568536 <br> 123 Main St. <br> CITY, STATE <br> United States of America <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-override">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="customer-name">
                            <h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-tools">

                            <button class="btn btn-link delete-card"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link card-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-summary">
                            <span class="card-label">ID:</span> 14568536 <br> 123 Main St. <br> CITY, STATE <br> United States of America <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-override">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="customer-name">
                            <h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-tools">

                            <button class="btn btn-link delete-card"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link card-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-summary">
                            <span class="card-label">ID:</span> 14568536 <br> 123 Main St. <br> CITY, STATE <br> United States of America <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-override">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="customer-name">
                            <h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-tools">

                            <button class="btn btn-link delete-card"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link card-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-summary">
                            <span class="card-label">ID:</span> 14568536 <br> 123 Main St. <br> CITY, STATE <br> United States of America <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-override">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="customer-name">
                            <h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-tools">

                            <button class="btn btn-link delete-card"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link card-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-summary">
                            <span class="card-label">ID:</span> 14568536 <br> 123 Main St. <br> CITY, STATE <br> United States of America <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-override">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="customer-name">
                            <h3>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-tools">

                            <button class="btn btn-link delete-card"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link card-toggle"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-summary">
                            <span class="card-label">ID:</span> 14568536 <br> 123 Main St. <br> CITY, STATE <br> United States of America <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
main{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-color: gray;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#wrapper{
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
}

.col-override{
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
.grid {
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.grid .card {
  margin: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  border: #ddd;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-shadow: 0, 1px, 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.grid .card.open {
  transition: height 0.8s linear;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.8s linear;
  height: 350px;
}
.grid .card .card-header {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 0, 3px, 1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.025);
}
.grid .card .card-header .customer-name {
  padding-right: 60px;
}
.grid .card .card-header .customer-name h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.grid .card .card-header .card-tools {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 2px;
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.grid .card .card-header .card-tools .btn {
  color: blue;
  padding: 0px 3px;
}
.grid .card .card-header .card-tools .btn.card-toggle {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.grid .card .card-header .card-tools .btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.grid .card .card-header .card-tools .btn .openState {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.grid .card .card-body .card-summary {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.grid .card .card-body .card-summary .card-label {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.col-override',
    horizontalOrder: true,
    transitionDuration: '0.8s',
  });

  $grid.on('click', '.card', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('gigante');
    // trigger layout after item size changes
    $grid.masonry('layout');
  });


  // Open & Close Cards
  $('.card-body').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    $(this).parent().find('.card-header .card-tools .btn.card-toggle i').toggleClass('openState');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your looking for but if you want a click on any part of the card to trigger the transition and toggle the icon, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
itemSelector: '.col-override',
horizontalOrder: true,
transitionDuration: '0.8s',
});

$grid.on('click', '.card', function () {
$(this).toggleClass('open');
 $(this).find('.card-header .card-tools .btn.card-toggle i').toggleClass('openState');
// trigger layout after item size changes
$grid.masonry('layout');
}); 
});
```